# sudo apt update error, plex and pi-hole not working

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, ppa, plex

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 (note: I am a complete novice) on my old windows laptop.

After a few weeks I wanted to install Pi-hole and found out I have an `sudo apt update` error.

Now Plex has stopped working as well.

The error is as follows:

```
maxim@bolleboom:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for maxim: 
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                   
Hit:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                           
Hit:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu/dists/artful/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have no idea what is going on, can someone please help me?

Comment: The error comes from the "samoilev-lex" PPA that you added and doesn't exist. You were probably following an old guide. Remove it and you should be good to go.

Comment: What do you mean by Plex and pi-hole are not working?

Comment: I tried to install Pi-hole last week and then I found I could not install. Then, yesterday, I couldn't access my videos from Plex, and this morning Plex even said my server wasn't connected.

Answer (score 1):

The name `artful` refers to Ubuntu 17.10, which has reached end of support long ago. As you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Esamoilov-lex), the PPA does not exist anymore. You can remove the PPA with the following command.

`sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:samoilov-lex/aftl-stable`

Comment: wouldn't I need to type remove instead of add?

Comment: p.s. thank you very much :)

Comment: *wouldn't I need to type remove instead of add? * No, the command is the same, `-r` is the modifier argument.

Comment: @MaxiTaxi kudos for asking questions before inputting shell incantations that you don't fully understand. Keep that habit!  A great resource to answer basic usage questions is the manpage for each command. In this case, `man add-apt-repository`, which clearly describes the behavior of the `-r` flag.

Comment: Allright, so I added the command and got this:
maxim@bolleboom:~$ sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:samoilov-lex/aftl-stable
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~samoilov-lex/ubuntu/aftl-stable'.
The user named '~samoilov-lex' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/aftl-stable'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'gamescope':  gamescope
 * 'labwc':  LABWC - Wayland compositor
 * 'neon-gamer':  Neon Gamer Remix
 * 'paperde':  Paper Desktop
 * 'retrogames':  RetroGames
 * 'steamos-ubuntu':  SteamOS based on Ubuntu
 * 'sway':  Sway Wayland Compositor
 * 'ubuntu-sway-remix':  Ubuntu Sway Remix

Comment: Is everything going good in the system?

p.s. thanks again, I try to learn from this, and so far, I am having a great time with Ubuntu

Comment: I got into the files to  /etc/apt/ map and read the sources.list and found the software&updates, where the ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful was checked, so I unchecked the box and now the system is all up to date! Installing pi-hole right now, as I couldn't earlier. Thanks, thanks and thanks again to all of you; I hope I have explained my own answer well enough for future reference (if people get the same problem) have a nice evening all!